# UIPrintInteractionController not working properly in iOS 13 beta device

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios13, uiprintinteractioncntrler

When I try to load printer in objective c code the printer view goes out of the screen. Can anybody look into this?

I have tried with delegate methods of UIPrintInteractionController
but presenting the printer controller goes to out of the screen.

This code works properly in ios 12 I want the same printer screen in ios 13

```
UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

[printController presentFromRect:self.actionsButton.frame inView:self.view animated:NO 
completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController 
 *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
       if (completed) {
           [self.actionsPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            self.actionsPopoverController = nil;
        }
    }];
```

**Screen Short Below**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: The same problem, searching for solution....

Comment: Did anybody get a solution for this? @RomanS

Comment: Has this been reported as a bug to Apple?

Comment: Yes, It works properly. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. But this an OS issue for iOS 13. This issue has been **fixed by Apple for iOS 13.1 beta**. Try to run your code in iOS 13.1 beta

Comment: if my application have tabbarcontroller as a root view controller and trying to presenting  UIPrintInteractionController it's not presenting...any idea?

Comment: Try it with a navigation controller